# Pass value of variable to complex command

Tags: bash, ssh, psql, scp

I am trying to pass value from string variable to complex bash command and I have problem with it. When I executing commands:

```
files=($(ls abc*))

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    scp $file user@domain.com:~
    ssh user@domain.com 'PGPASSWORD="abcd" psql -h domain.com -U user -d dbb -f ~/$file'
    ssh user@domain.com 'rm ~/$file'
done
```

I get some errors. Only 'scp' is right executed but lines after them go fail. I am seeing "missing parameter for psql -f" and "file not found / cannot remove dictionary"
What is problem with this code? How to pass string value to ssh commands?

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables.

Comment: I'd setup an SSH tunnel and run `psql` locally, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes will prevent the remote shell from receiving your variable. [Don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) [Quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) Use http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human review.

```sh
for file in abc*
do
    scp "$file" user@domain.com:~
    ssh user@domain.com "PGPASSWORD='abcd' psql -h domain.com -U user -d dbb -f ~/'$file'; 
        rm ~/'$file'"
done
```

The quoting here is slightly tricky, and won't work if your file names might contain e.g. literal single quotes. The double quotes cause the local shell to expand `$file`; then the expanded value is in single quotes to prevent the remote ssh from manipulating it any further.

I took out the array because it didn't seem to serve any useful purpose. If you want an array, assign it simply with a wildcard:

```
files=(abc*)
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! You describe precise all problem which occur here. Have a nice day @tripleee :)

Answer (score 2):

> What is problem with this code? How to pass string value to ssh commands?

One of the important distinctions between quoting with double quotes (`"`) and quoting with single quotes (`'`) is that the latter suppresses parameter expansion.  You need to either move the `$file` outside the quotes, or change to double-quote style.  Additionally, however, you should properly quote the expansions of `$file`, else you leave yourself open to breakage or even nasty surprises in the event of unusual file names, such as those containing spaces.

Moreover, the fact that you are formatting a command string that will be processed by a different shell adds some complication.  The easiest way to be sure that you get the quoting right is to use bash's `printf` builtin, whose `%q` formatting option serves exactly the purpose of quoting an arbitrary string so that the result can be re-read as shell input to reproduce the same string.  Overall, then, here's my recommendation for the loop:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    scp "${file}" user@domain.com:~
    ssh user@domain.com "PGPASSWORD='abcd' psql -h domain.com -U user -d dbb -f $(printf %q "~/${file}")"
    ssh user@domain.com "rm $(printf %q "~/${file}")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying each file to the remote host for execution, set up an SSH tunnel and run `psql` *locally*, connecting to the remote db via the tunnel.

```
ssh -N -L 12345:domain.com:$DB_PORT user@domain.com & ssh_pid=$!

files=(abc*)

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    psql -p 12345 -U user -d dbb -f "$file"
done

kill "$ssh_pid"
```

This has the added benefit of not exposing the database password, since you can simply type it manually or use a local `.pgpass` file.

Note that the tunnel is only necessary if the remote database isn't configured to accept network connections.

Comment: Interesting idea. Maybe one day I will use it. Thank you :)
+1